# How to checkout previous version of a file but without overwriting a file in git?

Tags: git

I know `git checkout <sha> -- <filename>` will rever the given file to a given version but I want that file to be restored but not overwrite the existing file

elaboration:

1. suppose i have one file `a.txt`
2. i want to create one file `b.txt` which is just a previous version of `a.txt` from some other commit

if i can just read that complete version of `a.txt` somehow .. i can redirect it to `b.txt`

Answer (score 4):

```
git show <rev>:a.txt > b.txt
# or
git cat-file -p <rev>:a.txt > b.txt
```

`<rev>` could be a branch, a tag, a commit, etc. `<rev>:a.txt` refers to a blob object which stores the content of `a.txt` of the revision `<rev>`. `git show` or `git cat-file -p` against a blob prints the content, which can be redirected to `b.txt`.

See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem).